# Using less than or greater validation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models the first model is entry this is used with my controller entry to create a new request.. I need to validate range_days from entry is less than or equal to range from my second model empaccrl..But no matter what I do Still get an undefined method range...

My Entry Model

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base


  self.primary_key = 'id' 

  validates :indirect_id, presence: true, allow_blank: false

  validates :leave_range, presence: true, allow_blank: false

  validates :range_days, presence: true, allow_blank: false, length: {    maximum: 2 }

  # Really wish I could get this validation to work ..............

  validates :range_days, :numericality => { :less_than_or_equal_to => :range }, :presence => true

  belongs_to :empaccrl


 attr_accessible :emp_id, :person_id, :emp_dept, :emp_no, :emp_first_name, :emp_last_name, :emp_mail_addr, :indirect_id, :mgr_no, :mgr_first_name, :mgr_last_name, :mgr_mail_addr, :leave_range, :employee_type, :seq_no, :range_days, :alt_mgr_name, :alt_mgr_addr, :alt_mgr_no  

# This is for the validation 
def range
  empaccrl.range
end
end
```

My Empaccrl Model

```
class Empaccrl < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection :vdev

  self.table_name = 'empaccrl'

  belongs_to :entry 

  attr_accessor :range 
 end
```

My Entry Controller with create method and new

```
 def new
   @entry = Entry.new
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html# new.html.haml
     format.xml { render :xml => @entry }
   end
 end

 def create
   params.permit!
   @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])    

   respond_to do |format|

    if @entry.save
      EntryMailer.submit_for_approval(@entry).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to(entry_path( @entry ), :notice => 'Entry successfully created.') }
      format.xml { render :xml => @entry, :status => :created, :location => @entry }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @entry.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

end

This is my entry table

```
      ID    NUMBER(38,0)    
      CREATED_AT    DATE        
      UPDATED_AT    DATE        
      EMP_ID    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
      EMP_NO    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
      EMP_FIRST_NAME    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
      EMP_LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
      EMP_MAIL_ADDR VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
      INDIRECT_ID   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
      MGR_NO    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
      MGR_FIRST_NAME    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
      RANGE_DAYS    NUMBER(38,0)
```

This is my Empaccrl table

```
     PERSON_ID  NUMBER(10,0)    
     IS_ACTIVE  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
     ACCRUAL_DATE   DATE    
     RANGE  NUMBER(10,0)    
     PROJECTED_ACCRUED  NUMBER(12,5)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated my eyes are burning from staring at this for so long!!!!!

Comment: I don't think you need the colon in :range, just try => range

Comment: This is what I got when I tried that .. @RailsOuter undefined local variable or method `range' for #<Class:0x0000000621d418>
Extracted source (around line #14):

Comment: define the method before you use it, I mean before the line where you use range.

Comment: @RailsOuter - you can't use instance method in context of a class.

Comment: Oh thanks very much BroiSatse. I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work!!!! 
This is how I got it to do what I wanted it to do thanks @BroiSatse for the help!

```
validate :range_days_smaller_than_range, if: :range

def range
  range = Empaccrl.where("person_id = ? and is_active = ?", '14052', 'Y').pluck(:range).first
end

private

def range_days_smaller_than_range
  errors.add(:range_days, "Sorry you don't have days for this request") if range_days > range
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this using built-in validations. You need to write a custom one:

```
validates :range_days, :presence => true
validate :range_days_smaller_than_range, if: :range

private

def range_days_smaller_than_range
  errors.add(:range_days, "LOL Nah! <Any error message or translation key here>") if range_days > range
end
```

Comment: Im still getting this error undefined method `range' for #<Entry:0x000000068abf50> do i have to add anything to my entry controller for this to work???  @BroiSatse

Comment: You don't need anything in the controller. You do have this range function defined, right?

Comment: No where and how would I define it...I'm a little lost          @broiSatse

Comment: In your question it is idefined at the bottom of the class, isn't it?

Comment: I defined range in entry as this   def range
     @empaccrl = Empaccrl.where("person_id = ? and is_active = '?'", 14054, 'Y')
  end
And I got this error (comparison of Fixnum with Empaccrl::ActiveRecord_Relation failed)

Comment: I tried this   def range
    empaccrl = range
  end

And I get stack level too deep error @BroiSatse

Comment: I tried again now i get comparison of Fixnum with Empaccrl failed @BroiSatse

Comment: @user3910236 - It is really hard to tell me now what you are trying to compare here. You clearly stated that you want to compare it with a range result - what is this number to represent? I do not know your system.

Comment: Okay basically I have an entry page for creating a new request... In entry i have a field called range_days and in empaccrl I have range what I want to do is compare the value on empaccrl to what they are putting in for the range_days basically to check and make sure someone isnt putting more days in then they have. so i want to limit what each person can put in the range days field to how many days they have in empaccrl. if that makes sense let me know or i can explain it in a little more detail . @BroiSatse